# Computation of critical value in F-distribution

Tags: probability-or-statistics

Is there a way to manually compute the critical value of f-distribution from this table for df1=df2=417?

It should be 1.21194

Thanks[image]

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. May I ask how this is related to the software Mathematica? This site caters to the Mathematica and the Wolfram Language communities.

Comment: Have you seen [`FRatioDistribution`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FRatioDistribution.html)?

Comment: `critValue = SolveValues[1 - CDF[FRatioDistribution[417, 417], x] == 25/1000, x][[1]] // N`

Answer (score 2):

```
Solve[CDF[FRatioDistribution[417, 417], x] == 39/40, x] // N
(*    {{x -> 1.21194}}    *)
```

If you need an explicit formula (for varying definitions of "explicit"):

```
1/(1 - InverseBetaRegularized[1 - z, m/2, m/2]) - 1 /. {z -> 0.025, m -> 417}
(*    1.21194    *)
```

Comment: I apologize. I just got confused. I wanted to post it in mathematics but i am new and made a mistake.